# Custom layout for Alert Dialog not working on older API versions

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog, android-custom-view, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to create a custom Alert Dialog. Got it working on newer versions of Android, but when i tested it on a 2 devices with 2.3.7 installed my custom layout is not visible (see Images below).

Here's the code i use to inflate & attach my custom view to the alertDialog:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adjust_layout_dialog, null);

mDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
            .setView(customView)
            .setTitle(mContext.getString(R.string.adjust_layout_dialog_title))
            .setPositiveButton(mContext.getString(R.string.adjust), null) 
            .setNegativeButton(mContext.getString(R.string.cancel), null)
            .setNeutralButton(mContext.getString(R.string.reset_to_default), null)
            .create();

mDialog.show();
```

How do I get it working on 2.3.7?

Layout on 2.3.7:
[image: Layout not visible on 2.3.7]

Layout on 4.x:
[image: Custom Layout on API 4.x]

Layout on 5.x:
[image: Custom Layout on API 5.x]

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to apply

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog"
```

if you use this theme in api 10 or lower it doesn´t work
you can use instead:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting theme to Theme_Dialog in my onCreate() like:

```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Dialog);
        }
```

indeed made my dialogText visible, but the main thing was that I was trying to display dark text on a dark background. When I changed the custom layout's backgroundcolor

`(layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE); f.e.)`

I actually found text plus buttons where being drawn.

Edit:

```
  .setInverseBackgroundForced(true)
```

On the AlertDialog.Builder actually gives a better result, giving the full background area of the custom view a light color while not changing the background color on SDK 4.+ and 5.+ layouts.